# Curl Post/Get as function in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm quite new in node.js and trying to make function which makes a request to a RESTful API.

i'm facing problem to return the value from my function.

Here's code of request

```
=> function curl_post(method);
```

^
return options for request below.

```
requested(curl_post('some_method'), function (error, response, result) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(result.status);
  }
})
```

Code above run well, but what i want is, to add "requested(){ }" to a function which is able to throw return value like :

```
function blabla(){
  requested(curl_post('some_method'), function (error, response, result) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        return result.status;
    }
  })
}
```

I've tried function above, but return "Undefined".

So, anyone know how to return "result.status", so i just need call function blablabla() when i want to get the value?

Comment: It is really unclear what the functions you have defined (`requested`, `curl_post`, etc) do.  Can you be a bit more clear about where these come from, and perhaps provide us runable code?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot `return` a value from the call back.  You have to call yet another function that moves the result forward.  You should check out some Node tutorials, or google "callback hell".  But, very short example, do this:

```
requested(curl_post('some_method'), function (error,    response, result) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        doTheRestOfYourCodeHere(response.status)
    }
  })
//  any "in flow" code here has no easy access to response
//  in fact, code here will probably run before curl completes

function doTheRestOfYourCodeHere(status) {
   ...
}
```